# How to integrate Facebook Insight in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am going to implement Facebook Analytic s through open graph api but i did not found any useful tutorial. If you guys some suggestion or useful link than share with me

Answer (score 0):

These links may be useful

1) [developers.facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/)
2) [github.com](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)